# Verifying the signature of a transaction seems circular

Tags: transactions, signature, verify, ecdsa

I'm reading Mastering Ethereum. Around page 116 it says;

> "to verify the signature one must have the signature (r and s), the serialized transaction, and the public key that corresponds to the private key used to create the signature."

But then it says that the public key is not sent with the transaction, that it is derived from the signature, and on page 120 has the math to do this.

This logic seems circular. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: From what i understand (I could be wrong, but maybe it will give you a hint) it is possible to extract public keys from (r, s) but you will get more than one. therefore you need to send the public key with the transaction to determinate which one and get the address of it. However ethereum use (r,s,v) and that additional v give you a hint on which one of the public keys is used for the signature. hope someone can correct or confirm me

Comment: check this https://medium.com/mycrypto/the-magic-of-digital-signatures-on-ethereum-98fe184dc9c7 and search for "The recovery identifier"

Answer (score 0):

Public key can be recovered from serialized transaction and digital signature. Lower 20 bytes of the public key hash should be equal to address of the wallet.